# CustomRichTextBox StrikeThrough TextDecoration

Tags: wpf, richtextbox, text-decorations

I want to add a `TextDecorations.Strikethrough` decoration button to my custom `RichTextBox` i am using the code bellow for adding and removing the `TextDecoration` the thing is that i am getting an `InvalidCastException: Unable to cast object of type 'MS.Internal.NamedObject' to type 'System.Windows.TextDecorationCollection'.` when i am selecting a range greater than the one that is strikedthrough and clicking the "StrikeThrough" button.

**My Code**

```
private void StrikeOutButton_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        TextRange range = new TextRange(this.MyRichTextBox.Selection.Start,
                                      this.MyRichTextBox.Selection.End);

        TextDecorationCollection tdc =
            (TextDecorationCollection)this.MyRichTextBox.
                 Selection.GetPropertyValue(Inline.TextDecorationsProperty);
        /*
        if (tdc == null || !tdc.Equals(TextDecorations.Strikethrough))
        {
            tdc = TextDecorations.Strikethrough;
        }
        else
        {
            tdc = new TextDecorationCollection();
        }
         * */
        if (tdc == null || !tdc.Contains(TextDecorations.Strikethrough[0]))
        {
            tdc = TextDecorations.Strikethrough;
        }
        else
        {
            tdc = new TextDecorationCollection();
        }

        range.ApplyPropertyValue(Inline.TextDecorationsProperty, tdc);
    }
```

the comment out code is also not working.

I was going to post the ExceptionDetails but i think that it's very clear.

Can someone provide me a workaround?

Comment: Any idea how to get strikethrough to work as button on toolbar for custom RichTextBox style?

Example being I want it to function like the EditingCommands.ToggleBold.

Comment: Sorry @Patrick95 it's been years since the last time I worked with WPF

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is that you will get `DependencyProperty.UnsetValue` if not your complete text is either decorated with Strikethrough or not.

So you may check for `DependencyProperty.UnsetValue` and just apply Strikethrough in that case.

I made a short test and this solutions works for me:

```
private void StrikeOutButton_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        TextRange textRange = new TextRange(TextBox.Selection.Start, TextBox.Selection.End);
        var currentTextDecoration = textRange.GetPropertyValue(Inline.TextDecorationsProperty);

        TextDecorationCollection newTextDecoration;

        if (currentTextDecoration != DependencyProperty.UnsetValue)
            newTextDecoration = ((TextDecorationCollection)currentTextDecoration == TextDecorations.Strikethrough) ? new TextDecorationCollection() : TextDecorations.Strikethrough;
        else
            newTextDecoration = TextDecorations.Strikethrough;

        textRange.ApplyPropertyValue(Inline.TextDecorationsProperty, newTextDecoration);
    }
```

Comment: it works. i used something similar when i fixed this. for somereason the link i provided as an answer was deleted.