# Getting error when I try to change TextBlock text

Tags: c#, xaml, visual-studio-2012, textblock

I'm following the Head First C# 3rd edition, in the first chapter it asks me to change text of TextBlock, but when I try I get the following error:

> InvalidCastException: Unable to cast object of type 'Windows.UI.Text.TextDecorations' to
>   type'System.Windows.TextDecorationCollection'.

[image]

The book suggests I use Visual Studio Express 2012 for Windows 8, and I am following the suggestions.

XAML Code:

```
<common:LayoutAwarePage
    x:Name="pageRoot"
    x:Class="Save_The_Humans.MainPage"
    DataContext="{Binding DefaultViewModel, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}}"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:local="using:Save_The_Humans"
    xmlns:common="using:Save_The_Humans.Common"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    mc:Ignorable="d">

    <Page.Resources>

        <!-- TODO: Delete this line if the key AppName is declared in App.xaml -->
        <x:String x:Key="AppName">Save The Humans</x:String>
    </Page.Resources>

    <!--
        This grid acts as a root panel for the page that defines two rows:
        * Row 0 contains the back button and page title
        * Row 1 contains the rest of the page layout
    -->
    <Grid Style="{StaticResource LayoutRootStyle}">
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="160"/>
            <ColumnDefinition/>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="160"/>
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="140"/>
            <RowDefinition/>
            <RowDefinition Height="160"/>
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>

        <!-- Back button and page title -->
        <Grid Grid.ColumnSpan="3">
            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <Button x:Name="backButton" Click="GoBack" IsEnabled="{Binding Frame.CanGoBack, ElementName=pageRoot}" Style="{StaticResource BackButtonStyle}"/>
            <TextBlock x:Name="pageTitle" Grid.Column="1" Text="{StaticResource AppName}" Style="{StaticResource PageHeaderTextStyle}"/>
        </Grid>
        <Button x:Name="startButton" Content="Start!" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Grid.Row="2" VerticalAlignment="Center" 
                RenderTransformOrigin="0.562,0.526"/>
        <ProgressBar Grid.Column="1" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="10" Margin="475,37,0,0" Grid.Row="2" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="100"/>
        <StackPanel Grid.Column="2" Margin="33,37,50,85" Orientation="Vertical" Grid.Row="2">
            <ContentControl Content="ContentControl" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Top"/>
        </StackPanel>
        <Canvas Grid.Column="1" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="100" 
                Margin="475,175,0,0" Grid.Row="1" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="100"/>

        <TextBlock Grid.Column="2" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="24,2,0,0" Grid.Row="2" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="TextBlock" VerticalAlignment="Top" Style="{StaticResource SubheaderTextStyle}"/>

        <VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>

            <!-- Visual states reflect the application's view state -->
            <VisualStateGroup x:Name="ApplicationViewStates">
                <VisualState x:Name="FullScreenLandscape"/>
                <VisualState x:Name="Filled"/>

                <!-- The entire page respects the narrower 100-pixel margin convention for portrait -->
                <VisualState x:Name="FullScreenPortrait">
                    <Storyboard>
                        <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="backButton" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Style">
                            <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{StaticResource PortraitBackButtonStyle}"/>
                        </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                    </Storyboard>
                </VisualState>

                <!-- The back button and title have different styles when snapped -->
                <VisualState x:Name="Snapped">
                    <Storyboard>
                        <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="backButton" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Style">
                            <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{StaticResource SnappedBackButtonStyle}"/>
                        </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                        <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="pageTitle" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Style">
                            <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{StaticResource SnappedPageHeaderTextStyle}"/>
                        </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                    </Storyboard>
                </VisualState>
            </VisualStateGroup>
        </VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
    </Grid>
</common:LayoutAwarePage>
```

Source Code

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.IO;
using System.Linq;
using Windows.Foundation;
using Windows.Foundation.Collections;
using Windows.UI.Xaml;
using Windows.UI.Xaml.Controls;
using Windows.UI.Xaml.Controls.Primitives;
using Windows.UI.Xaml.Data;
using Windows.UI.Xaml.Input;
using Windows.UI.Xaml.Media;
using Windows.UI.Xaml.Navigation;

// The Basic Page item template is documented at http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=234237

namespace Save_The_Humans
{
    /// <summary>
    /// A basic page that provides characteristics common to most applications.
    /// </summary>
    public sealed partial class MainPage : Save_The_Humans.Common.LayoutAwarePage
    {
        public MainPage()
        {
            this.InitializeComponent();
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Populates the page with content passed during navigation.  Any saved state is also
        /// provided when recreating a page from a prior session.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="navigationParameter">The parameter value passed to
        /// <see cref="Frame.Navigate(Type, Object)"/> when this page was initially requested.
        /// </param>
        /// <param name="pageState">A dictionary of state preserved by this page during an earlier
        /// session.  This will be null the first time a page is visited.</param>
        protected override void LoadState(Object navigationParameter, Dictionary<String, Object> pageState)
        {
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Preserves state associated with this page in case the application is suspended or the
        /// page is discarded from the navigation cache.  Values must conform to the serialization
        /// requirements of <see cref="SuspensionManager.SessionState"/>.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="pageState">An empty dictionary to be populated with serializable state.</param>
        protected override void SaveState(Dictionary<String, Object> pageState)
        {
        }
    }
}
```

Error Text:

```
InvalidCastException: Unable to cast object of type 'Windows.UI.Text.TextDecorations' to type 'System.Windows.TextDecorationCollection'.
```

Stack Trace

```
 at Microsoft.Expression.DesignSurface.Tools.Text.TextBlockEditProxy.Instantiate()
   at Microsoft.Expression.DesignSurface.Tools.Text.TextEditProxy.AddToScene(Boolean visible)
   at Microsoft.Expression.DesignSurface.Tools.Text.TextToolBehavior.AddEditProxyToScene(TextEditProxy textEditProxy, Boolean visible)
   at Microsoft.Expression.DesignSurface.Tools.Text.TextToolBehavior.FindOrCreateEditProxy(SceneNode textElement, Boolean active)
   at Microsoft.Expression.DesignSurface.Tools.Text.TextToolBehavior.BeginTextEdit(SceneNode textElement)
   at Microsoft.Expression.DesignSurface.Tools.Text.TextToolBehavior.EditDifferentElement(SceneNode element, Boolean returnFocus)
   at Microsoft.Expression.DesignSurface.Tools.Text.TextToolBehavior.OnAttach()
   at Microsoft.Expression.DesignSurface.Tools.EventRouter.PushBehavior(ToolBehavior newActiveBehavior)
   at Microsoft.Expression.DesignSurface.View.SceneView.TryEnterTextEditMode(Boolean textElementOnly)
   at Microsoft.Expression.DesignSurface.SceneCommands.EditTextCommand.Execute()
   at Microsoft.Expression.Utility.Commands.CommandTarget.ExecuteCommand(String commandName, CommandInvocationSource invocationSource)
   at Microsoft.Expression.Utility.UserInterface.CommandBarButtonBase.<>c__DisplayClass1.<Execute>b__0()
   at System.Windows.Threading.ExceptionWrapper.InternalRealCall(Delegate callback, Object args, Int32 numArgs)
   at System.Windows.Threading.ExceptionWrapper.TryCatchWhen(Object source, Delegate callback, Object args, Int32 numArgs, Delegate catchHandler)

InnerException: None
```

why i got two minus?!

Comment: Can you show your code?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30937620/customrichtextbox-strikethrough-textdecoration

Comment: Please paste the text of the error into the question.

Comment: @S.Akbari i edited the question

Comment: @EdPlunkett it is in the question.

Comment: @fluffy i am stucked in the first chapter that means i am learning, could not figure out what is happening in the link, and it is wpf my question is regarding XAML.

Answer (score 0):

i solved the problem by mistake, after i got error i changed Text value in XAML code, and problem solved, but i still get error when i click on Edit Text.

[image shows problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/f0FgM.png)

[image shows after solution](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vb3iR.png)

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem, and as it turns out, it's because I use Windows 10.

As far as I'm concerned, you can't build Windows 8 apps on older or newer operating systems - at the end of the day, this Visual Studio is made explicitly for Windows 8, so I guess it makes sense.

Anyhow, the solution to the problem is using the WPF version of the book. You can find it here on the author's Github page for free -> https://github.com/head-first-csharp/third-edition.

So what I did is install Visual Studio 2013 Express for Windows desktop, as specified by the book, and followed this route instead.

You start by building the same exact Alien Invasion app, and when I got to the point of having to rename the Text Block, everything worked out fine. So did the other steps.